# Enviar requisição get e receber dados

Tags: c#

De acordo com o PagSeguro, preciso fazer um GET e depois receber os dados que vem no formato XML [Documentação](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/guia-de-integracao/api-de-notificacoes.html).

Estou enroscado nessa parte:

> Para consultar uma notificação de transação, você deve fazer uma
>   requisição à API de Consulta de Notificações, informando o código da
>   notificação. A figura abaixo ilustra uma chamada à essa API, que
>   utiliza o protocolo HTTP e o método GET (as linhas foram quebradas
>   para facilitar a leitura).

Então fiz o seguinte:

```
string pagina = string.Format("https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/{0}?email={1}&token={2}",notificationCode, email, token);
```

Pesquisando cheguei a este código para estar fazendo um GET na pagina:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(pagina);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Porém não sei como prosseguir.

O que eu fiz, está certo? E agora como posso estar recebendo os dados do Pagseguro?

Answer (score 2):

### O que eu fiz, está certo?

Aparentemente, sim. Só testando pra saber de verdade.

### E como agora posso estar recebendo os dados do Pagseguro?

Enviando a requisição:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

[Veja como utilizar a classe `WebRequest` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Além da resposta do @Cigano, vc deve mudar o Method para "GET".

```
req.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```